# Chart.js parser returns the wrong date (suddenly back in 1990)

Tags: javascript, date, charts, chart.js, momentum

have a look at my code here. I am getting the data from backend so I am not able to manipulate them any further.
I got Chart.js as Scatter chart working, but the provided dates are parsed wrong 2020 becomes 1996 and so on.

Any idea how I get the x-axis formatted the right way?

```js
  var config = {
        type:    'scatter',
        data:    {
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "US Dates",
                    data: [
                    {x:2020-01-23,y:25.55,date:[2020,1,23]},
                    {x:2020-01-24,y:21.53,date:[2020,1,24]},
                    {x:2020-01-25,y:21.11,date:[2020,1,25]}
                    ],
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: 'red'
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title:      {
                display: true,
                text:    "Chart.js Time Scale"
            },
            scales:     {
                xAxes: [{
                     time: {
                        parser: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                        tooltipFormat: 'll',
                        unit: 'month',
                        unitStepSize: 1,
                       },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: 'Date'
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: 'value'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    };

    window.onload = function () {
        var ctx       = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div style="width:75%;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

And please ignore the "date" values within the data. This is just coming from the backend.

Thanks!

Comment: you have for instance `x:2020-01-23` in your data, that's the same as `x:1996` unless you wrap the date in quotes to turn it into a string.

Comment: `x:2020-01-23` resolves to `x: 1996`,  `x:2020-01-24` to `x: 1995`, etc. which is how the axies are being scaled.

Comment: @ChrisG—changing to `x:'2020-01-23'` seems obvious but it doesn't help either (try it) unless there's a setting elsewhere to tell Chart.js it's a date.

Comment: @RobG I know (I tried it), I was just pointing out that particular error.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for that. It was the combination of wrapping the dates in quotes and changing the x-achis type: 'time'.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to put quotes around the x values, and also set the x-axis type to 'time', that should resolve the issue!

I updated the display formats to show nicer x-axis labels

```
displayFormats: { 'day': 'DD-MMM'}
```

I've also separated the input data into its own variable, if this looks like what is coming from your backend all should be good:

```js
const inputData = [
    {x:'2020-01-23',y:25.55,date:[2020,1,23]},
    {x:'2020-01-24',y:21.53,date:[2020,1,24]},
    {x:'2020-01-25',y:21.11,date:[2020,1,25]}
];

var config = {
        type:    'scatter',
        data:    {
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "US Dates",
                    data: inputData,
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: 'red'
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title:      {
                display: true,
                text:    "Chart.js Time Scale"
            },
            scales:     {
                xAxes: [{
                     type: 'time',
                     time: {
                        parser: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                        tooltipFormat: 'll',
                        unit: 'day',
                        unitStepSize: 1,
                        displayFormats: {
                            'day': 'DD-MMM',
                        }
                       },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: 'Date'
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display:     true,
                        labelString: 'value'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    };

    window.onload = function () {
        var ctx       = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div style="width:75%;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: That solves the issue. Thanks for that help and nice code!

Comment: Great! Glad to be of assistance, happy coding!!